# Bootstrap Display Columns Next To Each Other

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, multiple-columns

I am writing and example application using bootstrap 4 and php. I am trying to get two columns to display next to each other at a certain breakpoint. Here is an example. What can I do to solve this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--bootstrap 4.0-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3" style="margin: 20px 0;">
                <h4>Search</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3" style="margin: 20px 0;">
                 <h4>Displaying ### results</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
                <p>Search field</p>
                <p>Search field</p>
                <p>Search field</p>
                <p>Search field</p>
            </div>
            <!-- at col-sm-6 I want two columns to display. how can i solve this? -->
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-6">
            <?php for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) 
            {
            ?>
                <div>
                    Record
                    <hr/>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--bootstrap 4 javascript-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for or your help. After reading your answers I worked it out. This is what I needed:

```
<html>
<head>
  <!--bootstrap 4.0-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin: 20px 0;">
        <h4>Search</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin: 20px 0;">
        <h4>Displaying ### results</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <p>Search field</p>
        <p>Search field</p>
        <p>Search field</p>
        <p>Search field</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="row">
             <?php for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) 
                {
                ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-6">
                        Record
                        <hr/>
                    </div>
                <?php
                }
             ?>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--bootstrap 4 javascript-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sigh. When is css going to have columns.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing to remember about Bootstrap is that each row **must** have columns that add up to 12. Instead of putting `col-sm-6` on each of your record container, what you'll want to do is instead put **`row`** on that, and add `col-6` to each of the `<div>` record elements outputted inside of your PHP loop.

This can be seen in the following:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!--bootstrap 4.0-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3" style="margin: 20px 0;">
        <h4>Search</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3" style="margin: 20px 0;">
        <h4>Displaying ### results</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
        <p>Search field</p>
        <p>Search field</p>
        <p>Search field</p>
        <p>Search field</p>
      </div>
      <!-- at col-sm-6 I want two columns to display. how can i solve this? -->
      <div class="col-lg-9 row">
        <div class="col-6">
          Record
          <hr/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          Record
          <hr/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          Record
          <hr/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          Record
          <hr/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          Record
          <hr/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          Record
          <hr/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          Record
          <hr/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          Record
          <hr/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          Record
          <hr/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          Record
          <hr/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--bootstrap 4 javascript-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, note that `col-6` will apply to *all* widths in Bootstrap 4, whereas `col-sm-6` will only apply to widths **larger** than 575px:

[image: Grid System]

Answer (score 0):

It appears you've got mismatched number of columns.

I suspect this bit...

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
```

should be...

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
```

Answer (score 0):

is this you want:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--bootstrap 4.0-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3" style="margin: 20px 0;">
                <h4>Search</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3" style="margin: 20px 0;">
                 <h4>Displaying ### results</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-9">
                <p>Search field</p>
                <p>Search field</p>
                <p>Search field</p>
                <p>Search field</p>
            </div>
            <!-- at col-sm-6 I want two columns to display. how can i solve this? -->
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-3">
            <?php for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) 
            {
            ?>
                <div>
                    Record
                    <hr/>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--bootstrap 4 javascript-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/48n2hvyd/3/